# es6: How to define functions inside a const?

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm doing this react-native project and i am using [this method](https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/organizing-a-react-native-project-9514dfadaa0#.u7ggwk3uq) to organize my project files but i don't know how to declare functions inside a const.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, ListView, Text } from 'react-native';

const Category = (props) => {

    const ds = ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged : (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

    // how to declare function here?

    return (
        <View>
            <ListView
                dataSource={ds}
                renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>}
                renderSeparator={// how to put function reference here?}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you called 'a const' is in fact an arrow function.
In JS, you can add any nested functions as you want:

```
const Category = (props) => {

    const ds = ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged : (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

    // how to declare function here?

    // You can declare another arrow function if you want:
    const foo = () => console.log('arrow');

    // Or a standard function
    function bar() { console.log('standard'); }

    // Even a function returning a function :-)
    function baz() { return function() {...} }

    const renderCustomComponent = () => <div>____</div>

    return (
        <View>
            <ListView
                dataSource={ds}
                renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>}
                renderSeparator={ renderCustomComponent } {/* Here goes your reference */}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete working code to define and use functions inside the **const** in React Native.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from 'react-native';

const Card = (props) => {
  function onPressCard() {
    Alert.alert('You selected the card!');
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressCard}>
        {props.children}
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = {
  containerStyle: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 2,
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    elevation: 1,
    marginLeft: 8,
    marginRight: 8,
    marginTop: 15,
  },
};

export default Card;
```

Answer (score -1):

In recent React Native versions line 0.60, you can not use standard declaration of functions. You have to use the arrow function. I used standard function in version 0.54 and I got error. Below is a link for a nice tutorial about arrow functions. Arrow functions will make coding easier for small functions. I have a professor before who will give you high grades if you use extensive small functions. You can re use functions later.

https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/es6/use-arrow-functions-to-write-concise-anonymous-functions/

Update:
Try the code below and change the ConsoleFunction function to a standard function without the arrow function. The React Native will throw an error.

```
import { StyleSheet, View, Button} from 'react-native';

export default class Mynewproject extends Component {

  ConsoleFunction=()=>{

    console.log(7);

    console.log( 8+9 );

    console.log("This is Console Message.");

  }

 render() {
   return (
      <View style={styles.MainContainer}>

        <Button onPress={this.ConsoleFunction} title='Click Here To Print Console' />

      </View>

   );
 }
}
```

Comment: Of course you can use "normal" functions, you just have to know the difference between them and arrow functions. And they have nothing to do with how big the function is.

Comment: What I meant about small functions is that the arrow functions was made to make it simpler for short functions. It is in the tutorial I just learned.

Comment: Find a new tutorial. That's completely false.

Comment: [link](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/es6/use-arrow-functions-to-write-concise-anonymous-functions/) I forgot to give you the link for your reference @JJJ

Comment: The link does not say that "arrow functions [were] made to make it simpler for short functions," it just says that it helps simplify them. Also, your example works just fine without arrow functions.

Comment: I would espouse to programmers to adapt the arrow function as stated in ES6 and continue to do so. It is an improvement over "normal" function. I would believe that normal function will be deprecated in the future.